# Дифферинцирование по графику python

Tags: python, diff

В проекте требуется вычислить угол по траектории движения тела.
У меня есть массив x(t), y(t). Мне нужно как-то выяснить, как y зависит от x (а четкой формулы нет), но это не главное, главное найти касательную к графику траектории, ну или производную. arctg(dy/dx) использовать не хочу, т.к. при dx = 0 невозможно найти угол, и sympy тоже не нужен, он медленный, а мне нужно максимально быстро.

Answer (score 0):

```
т.к. при dx = 0 невозможно найти угол
```

при `dx = 0` и `dy != 0` угол равен 90 (или 270) градусов (в зависимости от знака `dy`), так что смело можете использовать такой подход

а `dx = 0` и `dy = 0` сразу можете выкидывать, потому что по сути это описывает одну и ту же точку на графике

Comment: можно посоветовать использовать  atan2

Comment: да, или так, хорошая функция